# What's wrong with this PHP $_COOKIE code snippet?

Tags: php, cookies

I have an `input='text' name='fileName'` element and want to store its value in the cookie `filename`. When first created, cookie `filename` is assigned default constant `DEFAULT_FILE_NAME` If the request variable `fileName` is set (thru POST method), then cookie `filename` is assigned the value of this request variable. Otherwise, the cookie retains its old value.
. I try to do it using the following snippet:

```
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['filename'])) {
        setcookie('filename', DEFAULT_FILE_NAME);
        $_COOKIE['filename'] = DEFAULT_FILE_NAME;
    } 
    if (isset($_REQUEST['fileName'])) {
        setcookie('filename', $_REQUEST['fileName']);
        $_COOKIE['filename'] = $_REQUEST['fileName'];
    }
```

The problem is that when the request variable `fileName` is not set, the cookie is recognized as non-existent, and is assigned DEFAULT_FILE_NAME again. What goes wrong?

---

I have one form and three submit buttons on it which serve as main menu. If Submit #1 is clicked then I draw the UI for specifying file name ('fileName' element). User enters file name and clicks OK and after that it is assigned to the cookie 'filename' because file name is used throughout the app. (Of course, when user clicks Submit #1 and the cookie 'filename' is already set, I write its value to the 'fileName' element.). While I am within the UI created by the Submit #1 and 'fileName' elem is visible, everything is OK and the cookie is set/read successfully. But when I click submit #2 which draws UI for another needs, but uses the cookie 'filename', that's when the problem arises. I find that the cookie 'filename' loses its value read from the 'fileName' element and is assigned default value again.

Comment: What if it really does not exist? Why do you think it's there?

Comment: Are you accessing `$_COOKIE["filename"]` throughout your application? Why aren't you using a distinct state variable? -- The order of your code blocks is wrong then. And calling `setcookie` again when the $_COOKIE is already present is pointless.

Comment: If it doesn't exist I create it in the first line of the snippet.

Comment: @Etienne Kahn: how do you know it was created?

Comment: I echo the cookie's value throughout the code (for debug purposes) and it shows the cookie is created

Comment: Nope. If you `echo $_COOKIE['filename']` it shows that a variable you just declared is still here, it does not mean the cookie is created. Have you checked your browser and confirmed that cookie is there with the right parameters?

Comment: NEVER use $_REQUEST always decide if your data comes via GET or POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

> **Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page
>   load** with the $_COOKIE or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS arrays. Note, superglobals
>   such as $_COOKIE became available in PHP 4.1.0. Cookie values also
>   exist in $_REQUEST.

Try this:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['filename'])) {setcookie('filename')}

if (isset($_REQUEST['fileName'])) {
    setcookie('filename', $_REQUEST['fileName']);
}
else{
     setcookie('filename', DEFAULT_FILE_NAME);
}
```

UPDATE:
Maybe this:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['filename'])) {setcookie('filename'),DEFAULT_FILE_NAME,time()+3600);}

if (isset($_REQUEST['fileName'])) {setcookie('filename', $_REQUEST['fileName'],time()+3600);}
```

Comment: How does it answer the question?

Comment: Yes, I know about this and all my cookie-setting code is prior to any header() calls.

Comment: $_COOKIE is initialized based on the cookies in the user's request. It is not updated by calls to setcookie(), therfore you can't Access it on the same site as ist se

Comment: @j_s_stack: Thanx for your code fragment. I got your idea! But I need to assign DEFAULT_FILE_NAME to the cookie only once, when it does not exist. And also if request fileName is not set, then the cookie must retain its old value, whatever it is. My main problem is that the old cookie value suddenly disappears somewhere after submits. I really am baffled at this behavior.

Comment: Have a look at my Update, maybe its becouse of the Cookie lifetime, but I dont really think so. Did you had a look into your Browsers Cookie Cache?

Comment: I really am sorry, but that doesn't work also. It's enough for me to keep cookies only while the browser is opened, so default lifetime is what I need. Maybe I should better give more details on what my problem is.

Comment: Whats about a PHP SESSION ID variable

Comment: Please, could you look at my updated question statement. I have added general details below.

Comment: I would recomment you to use $_SESSION for this application

Comment: @j_s_stack: Great done!!! It's weird, but merely changing $_COOKIE to $_SESSION while having the same algorithms really solves the case!! Also, great thanx to zerkms and mario for providing insight into PHP machinations!